# Which data types should be used for Bytes sent in C++ socket/network programming?

Tags: c++, types, network-programming, winsock, winsock2

I wonder which data type is the most suitable for representing bytes I send via Windows API winsock.

I'm currently working on receiving and sending data frames on network sockets, as well as a CAN data stream. Basically I'm receiving data on a CAN stream from a measurement system (eg. bloodpressure, ecg..). Because of the CAN stream API I rely on, the data is received in `BYTE` (`typedef unsigned char BYTE` in Windows API `minwindef.h`).

Now, I'm looking to send the bytes via winsock2 API function `WSASendTo`, which expects the type `LPWSABUF` (`char*`), defined in `winsock2.h`.

Between receiving (from CAN stream) and sending (with WSA API), I'm doing several operation on the bytes buffer in order to create a suitable frame that can be sent. This includes "cutting" the received buffer, basically splitting the buffer using only payload bytes (e.g. bytes 3-7) and id bytes (e.g. bytes 1-2).

What kind of data type should the byts during extraction of information (creation of suitable frame with id and payload) have?
I'm thinking of:

- `char*`
- `std::vector<std::char>`
- `std::unique_ptr<byte>`
- `std::vector<std::byte>`
- `BYTE` from `rpcndr.h`

Comment: I usually use std::uint8_t and std::vector<std::uint8_t>, since that's guaranteed to be unsigned and 8 bits (char can be either signed/unsigned depending on the platform). Instead of using the winapi, you will get a much better C++ experience if you use boost::asio instead. (The Winapi to be honest is a bit of beast... and more oriented toward "C" anyway)

Comment: @PepijnKramer thanks for the advise, I'll take a look at boost::asio. So far, I had a fairly okay experience with winsock, although this whole multithreading with OVERLAPPED is more confusing that it should be IMHO.

Comment: Indeed the async model of boost is a lot easier to use.

Comment: dont confuse a pointer with where it points to. In your list you mix up pointers and actual data structures that store data

Comment: Why was this downvoted? A simple edit will make this question meet the requirements of SO. This is a good question.